# Hibernate firing unnecessary update.why?

Tags: java, hibernate, evict

I have three layers i.e Action,Service,DAO layers. I have loaded an object(of Employee class) from DB using hibernate with id 123.I have done some modifications to employee object.Later, I have create hibernate business object and done some modifications to that.

```
Employee e = service.getEmp(123);
e.setName("Ashok");

Order o = new Order
o.setNumber(567);

service.saveOrUpdate(o);
```

In this scenario, why it is trying to update employee object even though I not saying to save it? How to detach that from session?I don't want hibernate to update employee object.

Comment: Does your order class contain an instance of employee, and is it set to eager loading?

Comment: The "natural" way would be to not call `e.setName()`. Tracking changes to objects in the session is a fundamental part of how Hibernate operates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this scenario, why it is trying to update employee object even
>   though I not saying to save it?

I quote from the [hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-modifying):

> Transactional persistent instances (i.e. objects loaded, saved,
>   created or queried by the Session) can be manipulated by the
>   application, and any changes to persistent state will be persisted
>   when the Session is flushed. [...].
>   There is no need to call a particular method (like update(), which has
>   a different purpose) to make your modifications persistent.

And

> How to detach that from session?

Mark collections with `cascade="evict"`. Then [Session.evict(Object)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict%28java.lang.Object%29) the object before flushing on your object (if you have `FlushMode.AUTO` then maybe set it to `MANUAL` until you have done what you want).